# Nested styled MUI component prop types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components, react-props

I have an app that looks like this:

```
import MuiSelect, { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";

const App = () => { 
    const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {};

    return <MuiSelect onChange={handleChange} />;
};

export default App;
```

I want to create a reusable Select component and style it with `styled-components`. To do this, I created a separate component that looks like this:

```
import MuiSelect, { SelectProps } from "@mui/material/Select";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledSelect = styled(MuiSelect)``;

export const ReusableSelectComponent = (props: SelectProps) => {
    return <StyledSelect {...props} />;
};
```

Updating the `App` component:

```
import { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";

import { ReusableSelectComponent } from "./ReusableSelectComponent";

const App = () => { 
    const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {};

    return <ReusableSelectComponent onChange={handleChange} />; // Error: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
};

export default App;
```

However, now, after importing the component and passing in the `onChange` prop, I get an error - `Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)`.

Could you please explain why the error occurs and how it should be fixed? Also, let's say that inside the `App` component I want to further style the `ReusableSelectComponent` with `styled-components` and then use it instead like this:

```
import { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";
import styled from "styled-components";

import { ReusableSelectComponent } from "./ReusableSelectComponent";

const StyledReusableSelectComponent = styled(ReusableSelectComponent)``

const App = () => { 
    const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {};

    return <StyledReusableSelectComponent onChange={handleChange} />; // Error: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
};

export default App;
```

What is the correct way to handle these scenarios?

Comment: why dont you just type it as unknown? `const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<unknown>) => {}`